# How can I see which source safe project is bound to a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Is it possible to verify which source safe project is bound to my vs.net solution?

When I checkout a file in vs.net, then look up the file in source safe, it seems to be checking out a file from another project.  When I look at the directory in 'set working folder' it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File > Source Control > Change Source Control...** shows the bindings for your code.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, under the file or edit menu, (I think it's the the file menu) there's a menu item that says "Source control"... Under there, there's a submenu named "Change Source Control"  It's in there...